# Button not visible in AVD

Tags: android

Making an app. Last 2 button are visible in preview mode , but not in AVD(Google pixel 3a). Actually I'm new to Android. I just directly pasted the code if need more information let me know. Thank you

Snippet of code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/courses_offered"
        android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Fee_structure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/fee_structure"
        android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="230dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/orange"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Those margins values are the problem, you should use chekc the correct use of [constraint layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) Remember that dp is not the same as pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ConstraintLayout but your buttons doesn't have any constraint to initialize where they should be

For example:

adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` will position the bottom of the button to the bottom of parent, in this case, your layout

See this for further details and examples: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout?authuser=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constraints in the Constraint layout just like

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)

Try this code it will show you in AVD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="asd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Fee_structure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
        android:text="asd"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: As a beginners this was a great help. thank you so much. Also my college sir told us to us Linear Layout every time at top. He didn't give a reason . Can you pls tell why?

Comment: Its not rule of thumb that you always use LL at the top of the views and if you are using at the top of the view you must create a new LinearLayout every time you want to change the orientation of your views – creating additional Views and a more nested hierarchy it becomes complex to create complex UI. I sugguest to use constraint layout.Constraint Layout comes with some powerful tools with the help of which you can define complex layouts without having deep nesting. So it flattens the view hierarchy and gives better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have given height and width to match parent so your first button is taking all the space available in screen so you have to make them wrap content (height) and then constraint them accordingly